# validation on user input - Grails validation

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints, validation

Hi I'm a newbie on grails, im having a little problem now, i created an app which has a Log-in function. I need to set up the constraints where the username registered should not have a 'space' before the desired username, i don't know how to configure that on my constraints, please help.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two ways, use a regex constraint like:

```
static constraints = {
   username(matches: '[a-z0-9]+')
}
```

or use custom validator:

```
static constraints = {
   username(validator: { val, obj ->
       !val.contains(' ')
   })
}
```